# Encoding for JMF

Tags: java, ffmpeg, jmf

I'm creating some videos from a collection of images, I subsequently wish to play this video back with java.  I found JMF but I haven't been able to find an encoding which is actually playable by it.  Does anybody have an ffmpeg or mencoder formulation which produces JMF playable output?  I would also take alternatives to JMF if there is something better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JMF 2.1.1 - Supported Formats](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/formats.html) page, Quicktime and various codecs are supported for decoding directly.

Comment: I tried the sample mov file supplied by apple and it didn't work.

Comment: .mov is a container.  What actual codec is this Apple supplied .mov file?

Answer (score 1):

Two things, you will need to use the formats listed here: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/formats.html
Secondly, JMF still seems to have problems under certain resolutions, framerates and bitrates. I've found that it successfully can decode when the video to read, is not only in the accepted format, but of a length longer than 2 minutes. I don't know why; this happens to be my experience. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not stuck with JMF, you could try [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).  It will encode almost all formats for you (one of the areas JMF just falls down on).

Here's a [tutorial](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction#How_To_Take_Snapshots_Of_Your_Desktop) for Xuggler showing how to create a video file from pre-existing video images.